# How to get my craft projectConfig settings inside JS on the front end

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, php, settings

So I am trying to work with twig templates and I want to inject my project configuration in my js so I can use it.

I can do this

`{% set admin_email = craft.app.projectConfig.get.email.fromEmail %}`

And this gives me access to `{{ admin_email }}` anywhere in the document, just like `<?php echo $admin_email ?>` would do.

But I want to access these settings inside my JS as well. I have some tokens and other things stored inside there.

I tried doing this:

```
{% js %}
    let admin_email = {{ admin_email }};
    console.log(admin_email);
    alert(admin_email);
{% endjs %}
```

But in vain. How do I get the settings inside my JS variables?

Comment: What's the reason you're getting the e-mail from projectConfig and not `craft.systemSettings.email.fromEmail`?

Comment: It keeps giving me warning that is deprecated. This is the new way of getting it.

Comment: That's interesting, did not know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% js %}
    let admin_email = "{{ admin_email }}";
    console.log(admin_email);
    alert(admin_email);
{% endjs %}
```

Missed the `""` around the assignment. :)